# $routeParams not available during controller initialization

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes

I'm trying to figure out AngularJS and routing.  Can someone take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/spoon16/p9BBr/

Help me understand why `$routeParams.i` is undefined during initialization.  What is the appropriate way to use `$routeParams` in my controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically `$routeParams` isn't available until the route service has changed the route, meaning you should only inject the service in controllers associated with a specific route (the `controller` property for the route).

If you in some other controller needs to know current route etc. you should listen to [the various events](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route#Events) the route service broadcasts, e.g.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (ev, current, previous) {
    // ...
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9BBr/5/).

Comment: Having a bit of hard time understanding your first paragraph. In the jsfiddle there is no controller value associated with the route?

Comment: Usually you associate a specific controller to a specific route, and in that controller you usually want to extract the parameter values and use them for something (perhaps as part of some ajax call). I was planning on updating the fiddle but I could get fiddle to allow me to change the url.